# Code equivalent of TEXTSIZE from MS-SQL in mySQL

Tags: mysql, t-sql

I have an MS Transact-SQL string that needs converting into mySQL.

The transact states:
`SET TEXTSIZE 313131`

I've read their docs and the previous line sets the size in bytes of varchar, nvarchar, varbinary, etc, returned to the client by the SELECT statement.

As far as the size is concerned, mySQL's MEDIUMTEXT is sufficient, but it's much larger than the statement's explicit limit of 313131 in bytes.

I have no idea how to implement this in mySQL, so I'm asking for your help. Pretty please. And thanks!

My testing possibilities are limited, since I'm tied to big and slow tests that pass or fail the sql snippets. It's a patch-up, make-it-work situation, so I'm not allowed to freely experiment. Even a point in the right dorection will suffice.

Comment: I don't know if you can cap a `TEXT` type field in MySQL.

Comment: `LEFT()` function maybe? I can't say I've ever seen `SET TEXTSIZE` used on SQL Server either.

Comment: textsize does not limit the field sizes, it limits the data returned to the client as part of a select. So, if you have a pretty huge text field, then you only get the first 30kyte of text from it. I'm not aware of any setting that would accomplish this in mysql. You may need to use the left function to achieve similar functionality.

Comment: For MySQL alternative, consider understanding the content of this URL https://www.educba.com/mysql-text/ , please.

Comment: Guys, thank you very much for your input. I'll check out the LEFT() function, to see if I can use it in this case, seems adequate at first glance. @Shadow - your input was crucial for me, since I had trouble grasping what TEXTSIZE actually did and was worried I might drop some data unintentionally. I consider the answer to my question given through the comments. Much obliged! 

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.